# UICollectionViewUpdateItem action - unrecognized selector on iOS6 when deleting items in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, uicollectionview

I've found a wierd bug for my app on iOS6.

I am using a Collection view to represent a "tree structure" for my app. Each cell has a tableview inside it, and when I select a cell in the table view, i push a new collection view cell with another tableview.

When selecting a tableview cell in the "root of the tree", i need to purge the other collection view cells, and display the new one. I am doing this like this:

```
for(id e in oldData)
{
    if(i < indexPath.row)
    {
        [newData addObject:e];
    }
    else
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
    }
    i++;
}
self.tree = newData;

[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

This works splendid in iOS7. However, in iOS6 i *sometimes* get this exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewUpdateItem action]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3eedd0'
```

This exceptions occur on the row

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

I've found some threads about this particular problem, but it seems to be related to a keyboard appearance on iOS6.

How to find a workaround for this bug on iOS6?

Thanks.

Edit:

I think the cause of the problem is this. Check my new question:
[Subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout sometimes crashes on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659071/subclassing-uicollectionviewflowlayout-sometimes-crashes-on-ios6)

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/deleteItemsAtIndexPaths%3a)
Please make sure following things:

1. `indexPaths` parameter must not be `nil`. (Also you should check that `indexPaths` are not having any indexes that don't exist in your current collection view)
2. You have updated the datasource prior to calling this method.

e.g.

```
[indexPaths removeAllObjects];
for(id e in oldData)
    {
    if(i < indexPath.row)
    {
        [newData addObject:e];
    }
    else
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
    }
    i++;
}
self.tree = newData;
if([indexPaths count])
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I met similar issue before.

I resigned the keyboard before calling the deleteItem method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow findAndResignFirstResponder];
```

Hopes it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Dismissing the keyboard reliably is done like this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Also, you might have update issues, use:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
// make changes
[tableView endUpdates];
```

And always be on the Main thread when updating UIKit views.

Worst case, imeplement action so the cell does respond to selector [UICollectionViewUpdateItem action]:

```
-(SEL) action{
    // break here to find thread that is calling me!
    return nil;
}
```